# How to handle in ionic when the backend is offline?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, ionic-framework, web-frontend, release-management

I have an ionic app with angular and a backend with spring boot (rest).

The app needs the backend for all of its features (login, data fetching, ...) so it can not operate without its backend.

Now I imagine: The app is live and I have to update the backend for some reason. (scheduled or may be unscheduled (emergency updates)... After updating I would like to test the backend **before** enabling it for the users.
How can I react to thous situations in ionic? Especially when the backend is available but should not be used until I have verified it.

I thought about the following solution:
I place a text file on the marketing-website of the app:
"live.txt"
An the content of the file is either "true" or "false"... ;-)
But is this a good solution?

How would you solve this?

Comment: It all depends on how you communicate with the backend. If you have API that app hits to get the data, you can add something like maintenance mode that will return with the header of each API response, and app can handle the mode returned and display some modal or another page for example. Another possibility is to have app treat specific http request error codes as 'server unavailable' and display mentioned modal, page, whatever.

Comment: Nice idea. However, what if the entire backend is down and even the maintenance-endpoints are down as well? (all services came from the same server)

Comment: If you use interceptors, you can catch the problem of no response and handle it by displaying the modal that tells user that all servuces are down. You can also put a button on modal to 'Retry' calling the api/server and if response comes you remove the modal and if not - keep it up.

Comment: In essence, it seems that you need almost the same functionality/structure as if handling no net issue. So that might give you another clue and a path to follow?

Comment: Okei alright. But there is another use case: When I update the server, the backend is technically available again but not verified by me. So all backend access requests should be prevented until I give the OK :) I think the only way to do this is using another server which serves the healthstatus of the main server or using a proxy. I am not a fan of a second server because of additional costs/support, ...

Comment: Yeah all those are tricky situations especially when more spending is involved :D Anyway, while I'd certainly go with that handled_by_interceptor_that_gets_no_response modal for backend being down, the scenario of backend being up but not tested I would handle by adding a new status to response header, and if it reads like status: false, still keep the modal, and if it says status: true, modal goes off. So, in other words, bcknd goes down, modal pops up (on first request that gets no response), you manually (in API) change the 'status' to false until you've tested it all, then back to 'true'.

Comment: Ah now I understand. :D That sounds good! Easy and cheap solution, thank you!